# A simple problem with arduino UNO about optimizing code

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

It this a really simple code about turning on an off some LEDs, but I want it not to be so repetititve

I've tried to make a loop, but i couldn't get it, I did my best, but I'm really bad at this :(( pls need someone's jelp

`

```
#define LED 2
#define LED2 3
#define LED3 4
#define LED4 5
#define LED5 6

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED5, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(1000);


  digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
  delay(500); 


  digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
  delay(250); 


  digitalWrite(LED4, HIGH);
  delay(125); 

  digitalWrite(LED5, HIGH);
  delay(500); 

  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  delay(500);

  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
  delay(250);

  digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
  delay(125);

  digitalWrite(LED5, LOW);
  delay(500);
}`
```

Comment: write two arrays, `a_led` and `a_delay` filled with values you're passing to `digitalWrite()` and `delay()`. Then make a loop and pass values like that `digitalWrite(a_led[i], LOW)`. You can expand it to pass `HIGH` and `LOW` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll rewrite what [Oleg Mazurov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766387/oleg-mazurov) said in the comment:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_LEDS 5

static const uint8_t a_led[NUMBER_OF_LEDS] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
static const uint16_t a_delay[NUMBER_OF_LEDS] = {1000, 500, 250, 125, 500};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LEDS; i++) {
    pinMode(a_led[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LEDS; i++) {
    digitalWrite(a_led[i], !digitalRead(a_led[i]));
    delay(a_delay[i]);
  }
}
```